# Alsa creates driver with 32 bit sampleformat. I need 24 bit

Tags: drivers, kernel, alsa, ubuntu-studio, soundcard

> I have Asus Vivobook Pro 15 oled,with Ubuntu 22.04 in dual install with Windows 11. I have installed Ubuntu studio audio including lowlatency kernel. My sound card is PreSonus audiobox 1818vsl. In Studio Controls and Qjackctl I set realtime mode with performance. But I don't get lowlatency result. I could not get lower buffer size than 128 with 48 khz sample rate and 2 periods, same as with generic kernel on powersafe. In Windows with Presonus Universal drivers I get perfect sound with 48 khz and a buffer size 16.
> Now I realized that the Presonus is av interface made for 96 khz and 24 bits, and that is what Windows driver makes, but in Ubuntu Alsa creates a driver with 32 bits Little Endian.
> So I thought this is my issue. Am I in the correct direction and if so, how could I deal with it?

During my process of finding a solution to my lowlatency problem, I perceived that there was a driver or firmware for Audiobox 1818 VSL until Ubuntu Studio 18.04 that was lost in 20.04 and 22.04. The Asus Vivobook I have now had no reference back to 18.04 and there was many issues in trying to install 18.04 on the machine, mainly due to backwards incompatible hardware.
Could there be some solution to this?

Comment: The ALSA driver uses whatever sample format is reported by the device. Apparently, it uses 32-bit samples, of which 24 bits are actually used.

Comment: But I still don't understand why Windows on same computer with the same soundcard gets a good result with a much lower sample rate and by that a much lower latency. I also used the soundcard with my older computer, an ASUS f550j, and also reched a much lower latency without multiple xruns.  With that computer I made clean  update from Ubuntu 18.04 lts to 2204 lts

Comment: The sample format has nothing to do with this. Apparently, something else on the Vivobook interferes with the real-time stuff. I don't know if it is software, a driver, or firmware.